# How to search from many GAE datastore? Is it possible to use Search API?

Tags: google-app-engine, search, google-cloud-datastore

I want to create search interface to search data from GAE datastore? Can i use Google Search API to search this way?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, the Google Search API is for searching, well, Google Search.  If you can get your site indexed such that everything in the datastore is in Google's web index, then sure, you could use the Search API.  For searching the datastore in general, you need to write your own queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GAE's datastore doesn't really offer much in terms of full-text search (the kind that Google Search implements on webpages) -- there's a [conceptual example](http://simonwillison.net/2008/Jun/27/app/), but it doesn't scale up well, is barely documented, etc.

You can try something like [this example](http://www.devx.com/Java/Article/42216) (in Java -- you don't specify in your Q if you want to use Java or Python in your app), or [this one](http://www.billkatz.com/2009/6/Simple-Full-Text-Search-for-App-Engine) (in Python), but they're more like proof-of-concept (and quite instructive, admittedly) than fully-ready productionized components.  [nonrel-search](http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/nonrel-search) seems more mature but it constrains you to Django.

For a completely different approach, which does take advantage of the search engines' capabilities and APIs: if you can arrange all of your data so it can be presented into "documents" (pages generated when your URLs are queried), and write a [sitemaps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sitemaps) generator that guarantees to generate all the relevant URLs, then you can submit your sitemap to all search engines (including Google, of course) -- they'll reap and index your data, and **then** you can use their search APIs as you desire (including e.g. the `site:whatever.appspot.com` constraint in the Google search, of course;-).